# Simple TcpListener hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, http, tcp

Here's the code I'm trying: (This is just for learning how TCP works.) On my PC:

```
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
listener.Start();
using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
...
```

And on the server in the event handler of an asp.net button:

```
using (var wc = new MyWebClient())
{
    byte[] received = wc.UploadData("http://my ip here:3000", new byte[] { 1 });
    Label1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received);
}
```

I disable all firewalls, run the first code on my PC, then click on the button of the page (in my browser) to run the second code.

The first one just waits on its last line. Why? It should be receiving a request.

If there's a better way to receive requests on a PC (e.g. like a web page) I'd like to hear about it.

**Edit**:

`MyWebClient` is simply a `WebClient` with a limited Timeout:

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is .NET TCP listener adapter service running on your machine? For HTTP requests, better use HttpListener: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Roman I don't even know what that is. How do I check that?

Comment: You could run the server and the client on different machines, and then use [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to sniff through TCP packets. Maybe listener is not listening correctly, client is not starting the connection or they are talking different IP versions. If it is a client problem, try accessing to http://<your-ipv4-address>:3000 from a browser.

Comment: @Kiewic It seems that I don't have `NET TCP listener adapter` running at all. And I don't know how to start it. See my follow up question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410898/enable-tcp-listening-on-a-pc .

Comment: Is your TcpListener in an ASP.NET script?

Comment: @Kiewic Nope. A simple C# application. And about trying from a browser - not working either.

Comment: One more thing you could do to know if you are really listening is to run `netstat -ano | find ":3000"` from a command prompt. You should se a line like this: `TCP    0.0.0.0:3000             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6640`

Comment: @ispiro, use HttpListener class to serve HTTP requests, if this is what your intention is. HttpListener provides nice programming model and you will not have to parse HTTP protocol messages manually. Even better, create an IIS website or a WCF service, it will serve you best for most tasks.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping `TcpListener.Start()` in try catch I was able to get an exception. (net60)

Restarting hns service I was then able to run without issues.

```
net stop hns
net start hns
```

I would not say that this is a fix, but it explains some things about the underlaying structure. I would expect the program to hold the socket, not a service.