# Transfer information from website to PC

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I don't seem to be able to get my PC (Windows 7) to listen to any inbound information. Though outbound is working fine. I disable firewall and try many things. Here are my previous questions on the matter: [Simple TcpListener hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409703/simple-tcplistener-hanging) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410898/enable-tcp-listening-on-a-pc .

I now put up a simple site on the PC's iis with a generic handler (ashx) as it comes "out of the box".

And here's a web page's codebehind to access that ashx page:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
    Label1.Text = wc.UploadString("http://localhost/Listener/Handler1.ashx", "hi");
```

The web page shows the ashx's "hello world" message fine if it (the page) is executed in Visual Studio. However - when I upload it to my website (changing localhost to my ip as Google shows me) - it doesn't get any response from the ashx page. Why?

(I tried using `HttpListener` as was suggested to me in comments but got permission error messages. And anyway - this example now seems to indicate the problem lies elsewhere - specifically - that the computer is somehow not 'configured' to accept any inbound traffic.)

**More information**: The PC is connected to the internet via a wireless router. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Probably - check your router's settings for port forwarding. There are usually options to forward ports from your router to a PC on your network, often for online games. It's possible your ISP is firewalling out HTTP traffic too, so try a different port if that doesn't work. In general you don't want to use your home PC to host high-volume web sites, though!

Comment: @Rup Thanks. ISP firewalling looks like the problem here. I have to look into that. Thanks for that information. I didn't know ISP's do that. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Rup About not using a home PC as a Server - Yes, of course. This is just for a specific limited use. But thanks for the warning.